# ArcMap 10.8.1: Clipping rasters by decimal degree instead of meters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arctoolbox

My raster is in WGS84 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere) which uses linear meters. My data frame settings are set to display coordinates in decimal degrees (which are more useful to me in general), and that's what I see in the bottom right corner.

When I use the raster clipping tool (Data Management -> Raster -> Raster Processing -> Clip) it still wants to set the bounding rectangle in meters. Can I change that to decimal degrees *without* changing projections? That wouldn't play nice with some other data I'm using, and I'd rather not have to convert between degrees and meters manually.

Comment: Web Mercator claims to be in meters, but isn't (except approximately along the Equator). Clip always needs to operate in the coordinate reference system of the data.

Comment: How do I change the coordinate reference system of the data. then? I can only change the display units, everything continues to use the ArcMap meters units which I can't even change to UTM.

Comment: [Reproject](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project-raster.htm#) the data layer, not the canvas.